# Get index of ArrayList of various data types

Tags: java, arraylist

Novice java student here. I have an ArrayList that contains objects containing strings and ints. The constructor for the object is structured like this `MyClass(String, String, int, int, String)`. I would like to find the index of the ArrayList element using the first instance of String in the constructor, but I'm stumped at how to go about it. I've tried using `indexOf()` but have not been successful in finding the index of the particular element. I would be grateful if someone would point me in the right direction. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override equals in `MyClass`.
Depending on what you would like to achieve, your equals method would look something like:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (o== null) return false;
   if (!(o instanceof MyClass)) return false;
   MyClass other = (MyClass) o;
   if (other.firstString != null && this.firstString != null 
    && this.firstString.equals(other.firstString) return true;
   return false;
}
```

EDIT: You should override hashCode as well. When overriding hashCode, you should take into account the objects you took into account when overriding equals. So if you test two MyClass objects for equality based on property *firstString*, you should inlcude *firstString* in hashCode

```
public int hashCode() {
    if (firstString == null) return 31;
    return firstString.hashCode();

}
```

EDIT2:
What ArrayList does when you call indexOf is basically something like this:
'for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next) {
    if (o.equals(e.element))
        return index;
    index++;
}'

So, everytime you call indexOf(), ArrayList will invoke equals method on your object. 
So lets say you have a list that looks like this:

```
MyClass m1 = new MyClass("this is some random string", other params);
MyClass m2 = new MyClass("this is my target string", other params);
MyClass m3 = new MyClass("this is irrelevant", other params);

list.add(m1);
list.add(m2);
list.add(m3);
```

Now, you want to know the index of MyClass object that contains "this is my target string".
So you make a call to indexOf:

```
list.indexOf(new MyClass("this is my target string"), other params);
```

and, based on your *equals* implementation, it will return 1.

Comment: I'm looking at tutorials just now and trying to sort out how to apply this to getting the index of a particular element in the arraylist.

Comment: So the equals compares this with other and returns true or false. Correct? And the hashcode uses a prime number to determine if the result is equal to 1? I don't really have my head around it yet, I think.

Comment: indexOf calls equals method when looking for an object in the collection. if you don't override equals, objects will be tested for equality by comparing references to the objects. In other words, two objects will be considered equals only if they are the SAME object.

Comment: HashCode assigns a unique value to you object and is called when objects are used as a keys in collections (a map for example). It is common to used prime numbers in calculating hash code.

Comment: I think I have a rudimentary understanding of the equals and hashCode, but I still don't see how this leads me to finding the index of the arraylist element that contains this.firstString. What am I missing? I've asked my instructor about this and was told to google it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maggie - Thanks to your clear explanations and help I'm now able to determine the index of arraylist elements based on firstString. I made another constructor that only accepts firstString. I appreciate your patience. I have a much better understanding of this process now. Cheers

Comment: Always happy to help. But I would strongly suggest reading something on Java hashCode and equals. Joshua Bloch's Effective Java will probably be an overkill for you at this point, but at least read those two chapters on hashCode and equals.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at how to override `equals` and `hashcode` methods in your class. This is what is used by the api of `Collection` to perform this kind of operation.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think you should really be storing different types in the list ion the first place if you can avoid it? Is what you have really a list of objects that have some properties of different types?